# TYPO3 include an extension via typoscript lib

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I am using 10.4.16.
I wrote an extension, which works fine, if I install it as an plugin on a page.
It is a kind of news ticker and should run in the header part of the web page.
I have done it before with another extension, which works fine. But this time I don't get it running and I don't know how find out the problem or how to debug the code.

```
lib.header_ticker = COA
lib.header_ticker{
    15 = USER
    15 {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        vendorName = HGA
        pluginName = Showfe
        extensionName = Newsticker
        controller = NewsTicker
        action = show
        view =< plugin.tx_newsticker_showfe.view
    }
}
```

With @import will be the lib file included into the setup of the web site template. `showfe` is the frontend plugin of the extension.
Here the part of the template analyser:
[image]

I checked the source code of the web page, nothing of the code is included.

**Solution:**
Stupid mistake, forget to add

`<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.header_ticker" />`

in the template file. Now it works!

Comment: if your typoscript is not included: how have you included it? or what code did you use to include it and which does not work? and how did you include it in the page? (a `lib.*` is not included in the page by itself)

Comment: Bernd, the Typoscript I have included, you can see on top (lib.header_ticker). The one that works, is the mairlist one. In the mean time I figured out, the plugin `tx_newsticker_showfe` will not be called.
Is there any possibility, where I can see an error message, to figure out, what is wrong in my code? Can you see any problem with my `lib.header_ticker`?

Comment: what is missing: 1. how do you include your typoscript (`lib.header_ticker`)? is it a static template? which file? should it be included automatic if extension is installed? is it included by an include statement? 2. where and how do you try to include the plugin in the rendering of the page? do you copy/ reference the lib snippet in the page object? do you use FLUID viewhelper? ... (`lib.*` does no rendering by itself, it is a library of snippets for usage at other places)

Comment: You showed us how you create your TS object, but did you include it into your page i.e. via: `page.9999<lib.header_ticker` ? Also, as always immortal question: *did you clear the cache?* ;)

Comment: If you have a solution please write an answer for it. (as this can be upvoted and commented on separately to the question). see also  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat